# Wordpress custom CSS help needed

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I do have a styling problem on one of my wordpress sites right now! I hope that someone who knows CSS has 3mins to look at my problem and to tell me which CSS code I have to ente in which file.

Website is currently under construction. Please login with:
Username: admin
Password: 12web34
Link: [Link to Website >>](http://ahnenforschungfengler.ccsolution.at/)

On the frontpage you will see two side menus to the left. The first menu needs a little bit CSS customization.

I want that the hover and border from the second menu also appear on the first menu. Both menus are sidebar widget. Second one is wordpress individual menu and first one is a created with a plugin called WP-SAMW!

Does anyone have a idea which custom CSS code I have to use so that the hover and border will be the same on first menu as it is right now on second menu?

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Giving away login details will have you more crap than just a small css problem, gaurenteed

Comment: those are just the login details for directory protection ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code into css

```
.sidebar .widget_samw_menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks but does not changed anything! Did not affect the first menu!

Comment: thank you, hover is working now, border is still not as in the second menu. Also I guess I am missing a "padding"? Menu should look exactly as second menu

Comment: @BhumiShah Please don't make trivial edits from review. This review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11821101 was about to delete the answer. Because you edited it, the flag was cancelled.